# Where to store information for a character's abilities

Tags: c#

I am currently working on an rpg using unity 3D, and I have hit a roadblock. I have a few classes that the player can play as, and I can't figure where to store the information for the abilities they can use. I have a script to hold the info after they are initialized, but I can't figure out where to put the info so that I can pull from it later.

I have considered using XML files, but I realized that they were too easy to be tampered with by the end user. I also thought of using enums, but I can't figure out how to access the correct one when initializing. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by this "I also thought of using enums, but I can't figure out how to access the correct one when initializing."? You know which one to pick by how you define them.

Comment: When initializing the character, I would set up the player's abilities, and if I used enums, I'd have to access the right enum for that character's class. The reason I could figure it out is because i use the same script to set up all of the characters in-game.

Comment: Adopting a more obscure way of storing your data is not going to make it any more secure; once a client has your code on their computer, they can do whatever they want with it as they effectively control the environment it runs in. This is one of the reasons cited by many game publishers for using online authentication - a remote service constantly validates the client, the installation, and any session data. My recommendation is that, if preventing modification by the end user is important to you, that you need to investigate the various mechanisms available.

Comment: Another thing to consider is, is this a bad thing? Games seem to often be more successful when they allow the user to modify settings to change the game-play experience. If this is a multiplayer game then things need to be considered much more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the information in the exe itself.

You can do this by adding resource to your project and setting its `build` action to `embedded resource`.

Also use  [AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx) for **encryption** and **decryption** of data when you are writing to the `resource`.

Answer (score 0):

XML is not a bad idea. You could encrypt the XML data to prevent tampering, or store a checksum, to detect it.